# How do I hide 'Hidden' files?

Tags: finder, macos

I set hidden files to be shown with the following commands:

`defaults write com.apple.finder showHiddenFiles TRUE`
`killall Finder`

This worked as expected.  Then I tried to hide them again with the following commands:

`defaults write com.apple.finder showHiddenFiles FALSE`
`killall Finder`

This has worked in the past, but it doesn't seem to be working for me today.  All hidden files are still visible in Finder windows.  I tried a reboot and a disk permissions repair to no avail.  I'm not sure what else to try.  Anyone got any bright ideas?

Comment: 'true' & 'false' are predefined. TRUE, FALSE, XYZ all evaluate to an expression that is 'true'.  So TRUE is true, and false is false, but FALSE is true.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles false
```

or with a lowercase f in finder, depending on the version of Mac OS X. And then:

```
killall Finder
```

Comment: haha no way!  That worked, thanks.  Can't believe it was that simple! I need to wait 5 minutes to accept.

Comment: For what it's worth.  I just changed `ShowHiddenFiles` to `AppleShowAllFiles` and that did it.