# How do I get Sublime Text's open-file GUI to show hidden files?

Tags: macos

I know [how to tell Finder to show hidden files](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/32751/how-do-i-hide-hidden-files), but when I try to open a file in [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com), the GUI that pops up do not let me see hidden files.  How do I tell it to show me hidden files?

Answer (score 138, accepted):

You can press <kbd>⌘ cmd</kbd> + <kbd>⇧ shift</kbd> + <kbd>.</kbd> while the dialog is open, which will toggle show/hide hidden files.

In OSX 10.9 and up (Mavericks, Yosemite, ...) you need to be in the List View of Finder.

Comment: if they added a simple hide/show button it would be much easier and useful

Comment: Does not seem to be working in Sublime 3

Comment: @MildFuzz Works here (build 3059, on OS X 10.9.2). I think the file picker is actually system level so nothing really to do with Sublime.

Comment: my bad, I thought you meant sidebar (which is what I want)

Comment: On Yosemite, I found that pressing the key combination works immediately only if your file open dialog is in list view mode. If the dialog is in column view mode, you need to press the key combination, then change the view mode to list view and then back again to column view to see the hidden files and folders. That works for both Sublime Text 2 and 3.

Comment: Didn't know that – totally awesome!!!

Comment: To have hidden files shown by default http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/100384/how-to-get-open-file-selector-to-show-hidden-files