# How to get Open File selector to show hidden files?

Tags: applications, filesystem, macos

I would like my Open File selector to be showing hidden files.  I am not sure if the same Open File module is shared among many applications that use it or each app has its own.  The specific app I have in mind with which I would like to enable this functionality is `Sublime Text 2`.  However, I do NOT want the `Finder` to be showing hidden files.

What I tried to do is execute

```
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles TRUE
killall Finder
```

from the `Terminal` but that changed it only in the Finder and not in the Open File selector for Sublime (exactly the opposite of what I was trying to accomplish).

Comment: See this response...  http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/64324/how-do-i-get-sublime-texts-open-file-gui-to-show-hidden-files

Comment: Cmd+Shift did not work for me

Comment: Try Command + Shift + .

Answer (score 15):

You can use ⇧⌘. (shift-command-.) to show hidden files in a file dialog temporarily.

To make Sublime Text show hidden files by default, run:

```
defaults write com.sublimetext.2 AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
```

To show hidden files in all applications but not in Finder, run:

```
defaults write -g AppleShowAllFiles -bool true
defaults write com.apple.Finder AppleShowAllFiles -bool false
```

You can apply the changes by quitting and reopening applications. AppleShowAllFiles also affects other views besides file dialogs.

Comment: Similarly, for Sublime Text 3: `defaults write com.sublimetext.3 AppleShowAllFiles -bool true`